# Echo characters from busybox microcom to stdout

Tags: linux, busybox

I am using the busybox microcom program to communicate between 2 jsLinux instances via websocket.  Everything is going fine, and using microcom I am able to chat between the images.

However, I would like to also have what I typed echoed back to me, instead of only what the other person types shown.  I tried something like tail -f | microcom /dev/ttyS1
however this did not work.

The command I am using to connect the 2 instances (via emulated serial port) is: 
microcom /dev/ttyS1

Here is the busybox microcom documentation:

microcom [-d DELAY] [-t TIMEOUT] [-s SPEED] [-X] TTY

Copy bytes for stdin to TTY and from TTY to stdout

Options:

```
    -d      Wait up to DELAY ms for TTY output before sending every
            next byte to it
    -t      Exit if both stdin and TTY are silent for TIMEOUT ms
    -s      Set serial line to SPEED
    -X      Disable special meaning of NUL and Ctrl-X from stdin
```

Thanks.

Comment: If there is a programming context to this you might want to clarify it. Otherwise this might be better on Unix.se or just maybe Server Fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
tee /dev/stderr | microcom /dev/ttyS1
```

that would print everything to `/dev/stderr` (usually a symlink to `/proc/self/fd/2`) and pipe it into the standard input of microcom (or use a file instead of stderr...)

Comment: That almost works.  It doesn't send any output until I press enter, though.  Previously, I see every character on the 'other end' immediately.

Comment: That's probably because `tee` uses line buffering, while `microcom` reads the input directly. Unfortunatley if you don't want that I don't know an easy solution.